# How to determine which parameter set caused the test to fail?

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm running the following test set up.

```
private static object[] Test_Source =
{
  new object[] {"0", 1, 2},
  new object[] {"3", 4, 5}
};

[Test, TestCaseSource("Test_Source")]
[Category("Unit")]
public void Method_test(String expected, int in1, int in2)
{
  String actual = MethodCall(in1, in2);

  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Poof");
}
```

Only one of these fails. How do I report which one? Right now, I don't even get to see the text *Poof* - it just says that *One or more child tests had errors*.

Comment: Which test runner do you use?

Comment: @DioF The one which is built-in TeamCity - NUnit 2.6, I believe.

Comment: Using NUnit 2.6 the code you posted runs fine.  Is there a `TestSetup` or a fixture setup method that is not shown?

Comment: Yes. Both are present. Both are equally empty (i.e. *{   }*).

Comment: There's either something missing when you translated this to a minimal example, or something strange going on with TeamCity's runner.  To try and narrow this down, can you verify that your minimal example (i.e. the code you posted verbatim) fails similarly in your environment, both with NUnit's console runner and through TeamCity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, 
  string.Format("Poof on parameters:{0}, {1}",in1,in2));
```

Comment: The suggestion itself is great (+1). However, based on that I realize that the error message tells me there's something wrong with the case setup itself. I'm not getting the "poof" anywhere - just the error message quoted in my original question. Suggestions? I followed suggestions on source code at [their site](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6).

Comment: whats wrong with the case setup? what was the error message?

Comment: The reported error message when the test fails is "*One or more child tests had errors*". When I remove the source of parameters for testing, it passes flawlessly.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing when I execute it in the VS? Executing in the command prompt yielded the same result...

Comment: Well, I think when you excecute in VS it's not the same. As I see this situation, TestCaseSource - is an only NUnit feature, and VS may not support some of those features quite well. So, try to use native client nunit.exe Sorry, I has no opportunity right now to test this, so it's only my suggestions

Answer (score 1):

NUnit will report the failure by calling `.ToString()` on the object returned by `Test_Source`. If you change your type to something in which you can override `.ToString()`, then you can get some better error messages. Consider something like this instead of plain objects:

```
public class TestObject
{
     public TestObject(string expected, int in1, int in2)
     {
         Expected = expected;
         In1 = in1;
         In2 = in2;
     }

     public string Expected { get; set; }
     public int In1 { get; set; }
     public int In2 { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return string.Format("In1: {0}, In2: {1}", In1, In2);
     }
}
```

And you can change your test signature to look something like this:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("Test_Source")]
[Category("Unit")]
public void Method_test(TestObject testObject)
{
    String actual = MethodCall(testObject.In1, testObject.In2);

    Assert.AreEqual(testObject.Expected, actual, "Poof");
}
```

Comment: I just realized that this change probably won't solve your problem since it's failing before it hits the Assert call. :\